# insert a vertical line beside an equation

Tags: macros, vertical-alignment, amsmath

How can I write the below format of an equation in latex?

[image]

A vertical line beside an equation which specializes amounts of equation's variables.

Comment: Does the vertical bar have to be as thick as what's shown in the screenshot? Or will a more standard width do? Please advise.

Comment: In paint I draw by default thick line. But the thickness is not important at this step. However I think that  thicker lines can be seem more beautiful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the `\substack` directive, which is provided by the `amsmath` package, for the material below and to the right of the vertical bar. Depending on the desired height of the vertical bar, you may need to employ `\Big`, `\bigg`, or `\Bigg` to size the bar.

[image]

A purely personal opinion: I wouldn't make the vertical bar any thicker.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\substack" macro
\begin{document}
\[
a=(b+c)\cdot 8 \Bigr|_{\substack{b=6\\c=2}}
 =(b+c)\cdot 8\biggr|_{\substack{b=6\\c=2}}
 =(b+c)\cdot 8\Biggr|_{\substack{b=6\\c=2}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. The thickness is not changeable?!

Comment: It is changeable, but I really wouldn't do it. Good typography is importantly about *balance*: All parts of the equation should be roughly equally "visible". If you make the bar any thicker, what most readers will notice first and foremost is the vertical bar -- and probably nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

An idiomatic way to do this is using left/right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\substack" macro
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
a &= \left. (b+c)\cdot 8 \right|_{\substack{b=6\\c=2}}
  &= \left. (b+c)\cdot 8 \right|_{\substack{b=6\\c=2}}
  &= \left. (b+c)\cdot 8 \right|_{\substack{b=6\\c=2}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

This also has the advantage of resizing to the "contents" of whatever expression you want to annotate.

Comment: Did you mean to insert linebreak directives at the end of the first two rows of the `align` environment? A separate comment: The `\left`-`\right` method produces a rather small vertical bar since the material being  encases is just  `(b+c)\cdot 8`. Thus, the claim that this method "has the advantage of resizing to the 'contents' of whatever expression you want to annotate" needs to be taken wih a grain of salt.

Comment: Yes I meant to insert linebreaks. And you're right, but it might be improved if you also left/right the parentheses. But yeah, a larger minimum height wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I think a fundamental issue with the OP's setup is that there's no obviously correct "large size" for the vertical bar. That's why I showed 3 separate bars, one for each of three different sizing instructions, *viz.*, `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg`. For the case at hand, I don't it's likely that handing off the sizing decision to TeX (via `\left` and `\right`) will lead to an aesthetically appealing outcome.