# two line subscript

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

Is there a way to produce this?

[image]

`\substack` does not suit the need, because in that case `x=a` will take the place of `y=b`, and `y=b` will move lower to produce an ugly output like this
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to simulate `\substack` with `array` and have multiple subscripts left aligned to the vertical bar

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\xsubstack[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{0.65}
  \mathop{
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-3pt+\arraystretch\baselineskip}{%
      \begin{array}[t]{@{}|@{\,}>{\scriptstyle}l@{}}\\[3pt]#1\end{array}}}}


\begin{document}
\[
  \hat{n}\xsubstack{x_1=\beta\\x_2=0}
  \qquad\qquad
  f(\mathbf{x}) \xsubstack{x_1=\alpha\\x_2=0\\\dots\\x_n=0}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the different vertical position you can solve it without defining any new macro using the `subarray` environment (`amsmath` manual, page 21) (thanks to [the MWE by @Celdor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659377/38080)):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \hat{n}\Bigg\vert_{\begin{subarray}{l}
        x_1=\beta\\x_2=0
    \end{subarray}}
  \qquad\qquad
  f(\mathbf{x})\Bigg\vert_{\begin{subarray}{l}
      x_1=\alpha\\x_2=0\\\dots\\x_n=0
    \end{subarray}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449069/insert-a-vertical-line-beside-an-equation)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\substack" macro
\begin{document}
\[
a=(b+c)\cdot 8 \Bigr|_{\substack{b=6\\c=2}}
 =(b+c)\cdot 8\biggr|_{\substack{b=6\\c=2}}
 =(b+c)\cdot 8\Biggr|_{\substack{b=6\\c=2}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm... try `\substack{\mathit{long}=6\\c=2}` --- the substack is centered, not flush left.